# Javascript not declaring window size in tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working through a Lynda.com tutorial on responsive web experience. My Javascript is mostly working. From the instructor the goal of the JS is "we are determining the windowWidth based on the window outerWidth." Then we output that info and whether the screen is small, medium or large (the @media breakpoints).

As in, "945 (931+14) is large". [My work so far](http://liveactionliving.com/myWebsite/index.html) is live with it.

The problem is that 'large' isn't changing to 'medium' and then 'small' as the window width changes.

Thanks!

If it's helpful, here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/pandathorax/pen/domyEy) with all the HTML/CSS code. And here's the JS.

```js
/* JavaScript Document */

var windowSize = '';
var windowWidth = 0;
var actualSize = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
 
 checkBrowserSize();
 loadHero();

}); 

function checkBrowserSize() {
 windowWidth = window.outerWidth;
 var contentWidth = $('body').width();
 var sizeDiff = windowWidth - contentWidth;
 actualSize = windowWidth - sizeDiff;
 
 if (actualSize > 800) { newWindowSize = 'large'; }
 if (actualSize <= 800 && actualSize > 500) {newWindowSize = 'medium'; }
 if (actualSize <= 500){ newWindowSize = 'small'; }
 $('h1').html(windowWidth +' ('+contentWidth+'+'+sizeDiff+')'+' is '+newWindowSize);

 
}

function loadHero() {
 
 $('#hero').load('content/hero_content_large.html');
 
}
```

Comment: As a general idea - Make a func' to check window width, that then returns a result that tells you the size or the 'key' (e.g. 'large'). Then add an eventlistener for the `resize` event on the window, then use the result of the function to change the size on resize.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the function only runs once on  document ready. You have to bind your function to an onresize event so the function runs every time the resize event gets triggered (read about event handlers)

Here is a JavaScript example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

And here is a jQuery example:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_resize.asp